# why I can not trigger AzureRM functions from the kudu console

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Here is what i try. I am unable to do this from here.

Where should i do this? Azure CLI ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to log in to Azure non-interactively, using a service principal. The following command works for me, please refer to it.

```
$tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$appId = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($appId , $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $tenantId  -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]

For detailed information, please check [this article: "Log in to Azure Resource Manager (ARM) through Kudu to use ARM PowerShell"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabeshapiro/2017/08/11/log-in-to-azure-resource-manager-arm-through-kudu-to-use-arm-powershell/).